# Typescript property decorator weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

I have a simple class

```js
class Component {
  @id() instanceId: string;

  @id() secondaryId: string;

  log() {
    console.log(this.instanceId, this.secondaryId);
  }
}
```

And a decorator

```js
const id = (): PropertyDecorator => {
  return (target, name) => {
    const descriptor = {
      get(this: any) {
        const propertyName = `__${String(name)}`;

        if (!this[propertyName]) {
          this[propertyName] = 'MY ID';
        }

        return this[propertyName];
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    };

    Object.defineProperty(target, name, descriptor);
  };
};
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I do the following:

```js
const cmp = new Component();
cmp.log();
```

I expect that `"MY ID", "MY ID"` will be printed in the console, but I get `undefined, undefined` instead.

This example works as expected in [TS playground (link)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&target=99&jsx=0&module=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgExgXhgCgJQC4YAUBOIADgKb5QCeAIiaPgIZQj4oB8MA3gLABQMM+ElACu+MOij18AcyEAaGGHoBbEhjade-fqEiwEJCMHxwiTFqm59t-WVDRQAFnAg56YCuqs2bu6DCJCUnIKADkVEhQYAAMAfViAEg4AZSgTMGk0JVUMAF9ogG5eLR9+OAAzdABCJxcAbUDiMkpw1QBdLxLS-lqIBqDmsIi2qIByAFkATRgASSpRoutS3OKln0ERMRhe-qaQ1pI2xeW5Lu0SMGFVBgAjABsSHDThElO1nXByuGlRenvH7b4F5nXKLM4AeRuACtaFAAHQGL5gEgEPaUBxSOwKbKvGAGIwmMzMDDHGCg3jkni8YB3egQCAwADCIGURHAF1g3hgAAFEJh4Hp3MASDMEFUcNB0tIwdZeQh+RBaOAEFIKKLxTBJXAMjL+HcQJlOms-CAHnD9ZlenDtdAhSKEAorYrdCr8GqECSSiseN7qeB-MBWVFkQB3JkstnIsD2T08QNEc0GzAFIA), but not locally and even on [CodeSandbox (link)](https://codesandbox.io/s/hi9vbx).

What's wrong?

## UPD

When I changed `target` to `ES2021` everything became working as I expected. As far as I understand, changing `target` to `ES2021` automatically sets `useDefineForClassFields` to `false` and the main issue was happened because of this option.

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using locally? What is the transpiler output?

Comment: If you actually used `useDefineForClassFields` in your tsconfig, please update your question by [edit]ing it. I can then answer with an explanation on why this makes a difference.